# How to strip first 3 characters off filename in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have some files that I want to strip the first 3 characters off the filename
I thought this would work, but it just outputs:

```
MISEQPRF.txt
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

---

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%MIS*.TXT) do (
  SET oldName = %%a
  SET newName = %oldName:~3%
  echo %%a
  echo %oldName%
  echo %newName%
)
pause
```

NOTE: I will then amend to `REN %aa %newName` but want to make sure the name is correct first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion to use variables that you set in a for loop.

Try this slightly modified version instead

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (MIS*.TXT) do (
set oldName=%%a
set newName=!oldName:~3!
echo !newName!
)
pause
```

Also, you cannot have a space between the `set` and `=`, they must be joined.

Comment: Actually you *can* have a space in SET command between variable name and `=`, but the space becomes part of the name.

Comment: @dbenham Yeah I was actually testing that, if you look at my most recent edit I took out that bit, so it just says you can't have a space between `set` and `=`.

Comment: @BlueChippy Thats what signals it to use delayed expansion. I'm not sure I can explain it very well, see [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) for more info.